# how to detect OTP using cordova plugin

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have used this plugin "Phonegap-SMS-reception-plugin" but I am not able to install it from command prompt or manually.
Other than this I cannot find any other plugin for detecting OTP and fetch the data from sms from hybrid mobile app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is some file missing in that plugin. Use this [cordova-plugin-sms](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-sms)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var body = "";
    var address = "";

    $( document ).ready(function() {

        if(( /(ipad|iphone|ipod|android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) )) {
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', initApp, false);
        } else {
            alert('need run on mobile device for full functionalities.');
        }

    });




            function startWatch() {  // start listening incoming sms
                if(SMS) SMS.startWatch(function(){
                    alert('watching', 'watching started');
                }, function(){
                    alert('failed to start watching');
                });
            }


            function stopWatch()  {   // stop listening incoming sms
                 if(SMS) SMS.stopWatch(function(){
                    update('watching', 'watching stopped');
                }, function(){
                    updateStatus('failed to stop watching');
                });

            }




        function initApp() {
        if (! SMS ) { alert( 'SMS plugin not ready' ); return; }


        document.addEventListener('onSMSArrive', function(e){
            var sms = e.data;

            body = sms.body;
            address = sms.address;

        });
    }


    </script>
```

Be sure that the app has read sms permission granted in Marshmallow.

Comment: Hello 
I tried it but no luck.
It is not reading my OTP.
I have the following configuration :
Android version - android 7.1.4
Cordova version - 8.1.2

My code is
After OTP req API call

initApp(); // call function

//function defination 

initApp : function() {
 if (! SMS ) { alert( 'SMS plugin not ready' );
console.log('SMS plugin not ready');
return; }else{
console.log('SMS plugin is ready');
}
document.addEventListener('onSMSArrive', function(e){
var sms = e.data;
console.log('SMS is ',sms);
body = sms.body;
 address = sms.address;
        });
    },
Help me

Comment: @rahul.sapkal23 make sure the app has read SMS permission. Have you checked console ?